# Deserialize nested fields in marshmallow

Tags: python, transformation, preprocessor, marshmallow

I'm consuming an API that returns something like:

```
{'name': 'foo', 'start': {'date': '2016-06-19', 'time': '18:00'}}
```

And I want to desearialize it with marshmallow to get only the name and the start date, so the desired result would be the following:

```
{'name': 'foo', 'date': '2016-06-19'}
```

But I haven't found any way to get the date, this what I have tried:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, pprint

event = {'name': 'foo', 'start': {'date': '2016-06-19', 'time': '18:00'}}
class EventSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    date = fields.Str(load_from='start.date')


schema = EventSchema()
result = schema.load(event)
pprint(result.data)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to create a `NestedSchema` for the nested dictionary, and overwrite your parent schema's `load` method to append the nested field to parent. Specify a `only` attribute so the `Nested` field does not fetch all of its items:

```
class DateTimeSchema(Schema):
    date = fields.Str()
    time = fields.Str()


class EventSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    date = fields.Nested(DateTimeSchema, load_from='start', only='date')

    def load(self, *args, special=None):
        _partial = super(EventSchema, self).load(*args)

        # Move special field from Nest to Parent
        if special is not None and special in _partial.data:
            _partial.data[special]  = _partial.data[special].get(special)
        return _partial
```

And setting up your schema instance like so:

```
event = {'name': 'foo', 'start': {'date': '2016-06-19', 'time': '18:00'}}

schema, special_field = EventSchema(), 'date'
result = schema.load(event, special=special_field)
pprint(result.data)
# {'name': 'foo', 'date': '2016-06-19'}
```

You can always fine tune to your taste.

Comment: You can also cut the story short with lambdas, http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_fields.html#function-fields, doing something like this: `date = fields.Function(load_from='start', load_only=True, deserialize=lambda start: start['date'])`.

Comment: @LukaŽitnik but then you loose the validation.

Answer (score 21):

What you describe can be accomplished by **transforming*** your input data in a **pre-processing*** step. While the accepted answer looks like it will do that, [Marshmallow has built-in decorators](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html?highlight=uid#module-marshmallow.decorators) to allow you to accomplish this in a way that I think is even clearer:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, pre_load, fields, pprint

event = {'name': 'foo', 'start': {'date': '2016-06-19', 'time': '18:00'}}
expected = {'name': 'foo', 'date': '2016-06-19'}


class EventSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    # Marshmallow 2
    date = fields.Str(load_from='date')
    # Marshmallow 3
    date = fields.Str(data_key='date')

    @pre_load
    def move_date(self, data):
        """This will alter the data passed to ``load()`` before Marshmallow
        attempts deserialization.
        """
        start = data.pop('start')
        data['date'] = start['date']
        return data

schema = EventSchema()
result = schema.load(event)
pprint(result.data)

assert result.data == expected
```

* **transform** and **pre-process** are terms of art in the domain of object modeling and data processing. I bolded them because knowing these might help folks who read this question successfully Google for answers to related questions.

Comment: I think that `load_from='start.date'` is incorrect here

Comment: Excellent answer. This might benefit from a review of the latest documentation, as this may be non-obvious to developers who are not familiar with decorator syntax in python.

Comment: Just a heads up, as of version 3.0.0b8 `load_from` and `dump_to` were replaced with the `data_key` parameter: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html?highlight=load_from#module-marshmallow.fields

Answer (score 3):

**Marshmallow 3 has `Pluck`:**

```
class DateTimeSchema(Schema):
    date = fields.Str()
    time = fields.Str()

class EventSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    date = fields.Pluck(DateTimeSchema, 'date')
```

[documentation for `fields.Pluck()`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Pluck)

Comment: Isn't `Pluck` the opposite of what @camaya is asking for?  I think camaya needs to "pluck" a field during *deserialization*, whereas `Pluck` plucks a field out for *serialization*, if I'm reading the docs right?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how complex the previous answers are, I want to offer a very simple solution (using `fields.Function`):

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class EventSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    date = fields.Function(data_key='start',
                           deserialize=lambda start: start['date'])

schema = EventSchema()
event = {'name': 'foo', 'start': {'date': '2016-06-19', 'time': '18:00'}}
result = schema.load(event)
print(result)
```

The result is as expected: `{'name': 'foo', 'date': '2016-06-19'}`.

This works on version 3 of `marshmallow`.